# How to display strings in activity 3 from activity 1, 2?

Tags: android

I need to get strings values from two different activities say activity1 and activity2, each activity should have maximum 4 edittext field..so totally eight fields should be displayed orderly in activity3. I have tried the code which is not displaying in the activity3.

Look at code,

Activity1

```
String namef = fname.getText().toString();
Intent first = new Intent(AssessmentActivity.this, Second.class);
first.putExtra("list1", namef);
startActivity(first);

String namel = lname.getText().toString();
Intent second = new Intent(AssessmentActivity.this, Second.class);
second.putExtra("list2", namel);
startActivity(second);

String phone = mob.getText().toString();
Intent third = new Intent(AssessmentActivity.this, Second.class);
third.putExtra("list3", phone);
startActivity(third);   

String mailid = email.getText().toString();
Intent fourth = new Intent(AssessmentActivity.this, Second.class);
fourth.putExtra("list4", mailid);
startActivity(fourth);
```

**Activity2**

```
String cont = addr.getText().toString();
Intent fifth = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
fifth.putExtra("list5", cont);
startActivity(fifth);

String db = dob.getText().toString();
Intent sixth = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
sixth.putExtra("list6", db);
startActivity(sixth);

String nation = citizen.getText().toString();
Intent Seventh = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
Seventh.putExtra("list7", nation);
startActivity(Seventh);

String subject = course.getText().toString();
Intent Eight = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
Eight.putExtra("list8", subject);
startActivity(Eight);
```

****Activity3****

```
TextView first = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
String fieldone = getIntent().getStringExtra("list1" );
first.setText(fieldone);

TextView second = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
String fieldtwo = getIntent().getStringExtra("list2" );
second.setText(fieldtwo);

TextView third = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
String fieldthree = getIntent().getStringExtra("list3" );
third.setText(fieldthree);

TextView fourth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
String fieldfour = getIntent().getStringExtra("list4" );
fourth.setText(fieldfour);

TextView fifth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
String fieldfive = getIntent().getStringExtra("list5" );
fifth.setText(fieldfive);

TextView sixth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
String fieldsix = getIntent().getStringExtra("list6" );
sixth.setText(fieldsix);

TextView seventh = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
String fieldseven = getIntent().getStringExtra("list7" );
seventh.setText(fieldseven);

TextView eight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
String fieldeight = getIntent().getStringExtra("list8");
eight.setText(fieldeight);
```

Comment: Are you receiving them in onCreate in Activity3? also when you receive data in Activity2 from Activity1 you need to send them to Actvity 3.

Comment: Yes receiving them in onCreate in Activity3. It is passing values from Activity2 to Activity3 but cant get values from Activity1 to Activity3. Dont dnow how to save values in Activity2 from Activity1 to display in Activity3.

Comment: args.putString("list1",getIntent().getExtras().getString("namef")) is this how you do it? make sure you use same key names to send and receive

Comment: Thanks for the comments Omid, code is now working as expected. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pass all of them into the new activity, not start a new activity with each.

```
Intent first = new Intent(AssessmentActivity.this, Second.class);

String namef = fname.getText().toString();
first.putExtra("list1", namef);

String namel = lname.getText().toString();
first.putExtra("list2", namel);

String phone = mob.getText().toString();
first.putExtra("list3", phone);

String mailid = email.getText().toString();
first.putExtra("list4", mailid);

startActivity(first);
```

Then when in your Second (the second activity)'s onCreate you can pull each of those and store them. Then when you're sending to the Third you can add each back in to the intent.

```
Intent fifth = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);

fifth.putExtra("list1", namef_stored);
fifth.putExtra("list2", namel_stored);
fifth.putExtra("list3", phone_stored);
fifth.putExtra("list4", mailid_stored);

String cont = addr.getText().toString();
fifth.putExtra("list5", cont);

String db = dob.getText().toString();
fifth.putExtra("list6", db);

String nation = citizen.getText().toString();
fifth.putExtra("list7", nation);

String subject = course.getText().toString();
fifth.putExtra("list8", subject);

startActivity(fifth);
```

Comment: The way you explained made me to understood at single glance. thank you very much Eric. You are a good teacher!